# cpCCSprite moving out of Window Containment in cocos 2d Spacemanager framework

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Cocos2D - spacemanager framework, and stuck at a problem.
I have created a window containment for the gravity using below code..

```
[spaceManager addWindowContainmentWithFriction:1.0 elasticity:1.0 inset:cpvzero];
```

Now I created a cpCCSprite object and added it to the CCScene.
I am trying to applyImpulse to this cpCCSprite object when a touch is detected near the sprite.

```
[sprite applyImpulse:cpvmult(vector, magnitude)];
```

This works fine when the *magnitude* is less, but if it is a high value say 1000 or 1500,
the sprite moves out of the window containment added and is disappearing from the screen for the detected touch.
I am using cocos v2.x with spacemanager framework v0.3.0.
Please help me in fixing this.

Comment: Have you tried setting the radius to a higher value for the wall segments? >> https://github.com/robertblackwood/Chipmunk-Spacemanager/blob/master/src/SpaceManager.mm#L581

Comment: Yes, I have tried with radius of 1 and 100. It behaves in the same way for both the radius.

Comment: Without seeing a small sample of code that can reproduce the behavior it's impossible to say. I would guess that the object is moving _over_ the wall in a single timestep, so it won't trigger a collision.  Chipmunk2d doesn't do swept collisions ( yet. ? ) The simple answer is to slow things down. Have you tried setting the velocity limit on the object?  cpBodySetVelLimit( body, limit) .